# Using separate command with bar graphs offsets the position of graphs

Tags: graph, stata

I have a pretty simple Stata dataset that I am trying to plot as a bar graph:

```
clear

input group acc_count
1 2529
2 530
3 437
end
```

However, the bars are offset for some reason while I would like them equally spaced and centered:

[image]

Note that I first used the `separate` command because group `2` is of interest and I wanted it colored differently from the other two groups:

```
separate acc_count, by(Group==2)

graph bar (mean) acc_count0 acc_count1, over(Group) graphregion(color(white)) legend(off)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `graph twoway bar` command instead:

```
twoway (bar acc_count group, barwidth(0.2) base(0) graphregion(color(white))) ///
       (bar acc_count group if group == 2, color(red) barwidth(0.2) xlabel(#3) legend(off))
```

If you insist on using the `separate` command first, the syntax of `twoway bar` should be as follows:

```
twoway bar acc_count? group, color(navy red) ///
                             barwidth(0.2 0.2) ///
                             base(0) ///
                             xlabel(#3) ///
                             graphregion(color(white)) ///
                             legend(off)
```

The result in both cases is the same:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code below results in equally spaced bars:

```
graph bar acc_count, over(group)
```

[image]

Comment: I should have specified this earlier that the reason I used the `separate` command was because group 2 is a  group of interest and I want it colored differently from the others. Using the `separate` command automatically does that for the group of interest (group 2). Updated my question to reflect this.